# OpenCV: Error with adaptive thresholding (Error -215)

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to do adaptive thresholding after applying Sobel filtering on an image, as seen in the code below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("train.jpg")
img = np.array(image, dtype=np.uint8)

#convert to greyscale
img_grey = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#remove noise
img_smooth = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_grey, (13,13), 0)

sobely = cv2.Sobel(img_smooth,cv2.CV_64F,0,1,ksize=9)

thres = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(sobely, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,
                          cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 73, 2)
```

However, when I try to do adaptive thresholding, I get the following error:

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv- 
python/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/thresh.cpp:1627: error: (-215:Assertion 
failed) src.type() == CV_8UC1 in function 'adaptiveThreshold'
```

I have read that this error occurs if your image is not greyscale, however, I converted my image to greyscale at the start of the code. I am not sure why I am getting this error. Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you read is correct, that error actually means that your `Mat` is not a gray-scale image.

That happens because `Sobel` is changing the data to `cv2.CV_64F` (see the second parameter in the documentation [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gacea54f142e81b6758cb6f375ce782c8d)).
So after Sobel you need to convert the image to a gray-scale, you can do that with [convertScaleAbs](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga3460e9c9f37b563ab9dd550c4d8c4e7d) and after that pass it's output to `adaptiveThreshold`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have read the documentation for convertScaleAbs but I am not sure exactly how it converts an image to greyscale. In the docs it says the function 'Scales, calculates absolute values, and converts the result to 8-bit'. How does this function convert the image to greyscale?

Comment: Well, that 8-bit result is the gray-scale image. The gray-scale image is a matrix where each pixel has values between 0 and 255 (8 bit). I have wrote an answer to your other question, that contains the python code.